# For which value(s) of t is an eigenvector

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I am looking for a better approach to the following problem. I am trying to take the determinant of the matrix but it is leading to an unfactorable equation. Any guidance would be very much appreciated, thank you so much.

[image]

EDIT: Now i'm here. How do I solve this system?

[image]

Comment: Did you do the corresponding multiplication? And what did you get after it?

Comment: @Shashi I get `(2-X)(-1-X) - 3t` which comes out to `-2 - 3X + X^2 - 3t` where X is lambda, Im not sure where to go from here.

Comment: I meant the calculation $Ax$

Comment: @Kevindoesmath See my answer. You don't need to do so much work.

Answer (score 3):

Hint:

Recall that an eigenvector $v$ of $A$ satisfies the property that it is mapped to a scaled version of itself. I.e. $Av=\lambda v$. So we just shrink or lengthen the vector $v$, but keep its direction fixed.

So you can simply just calculate $Ax$ with $t$ left unknown, and see which choice of $t$ will satisfy this requirement.

---

If you show some work I can verify your solution, give more assistance.

Comment: Thanks for the guidance. I posted a progress pic.

Comment: @Kevindoesmath The first line of what you wrote, look at that, and note that you have $x_1=2$ and $x_2=1$. You have two equations and you have unknowns $\lambda$ and $t$.

The second line of what you wrote is wrong, unless $(x_1,x_2)$ was an eigenvector with eigenvalue $\lambda =1$.